# Proof software for Primitive Recursive Arithmetic

Tags: computability, proof-assistants

Primitive Recursive Arithmetic is a critical foundational system in mathematics at large, and all the more so in areas studying constructive reasoning and/or computability such as Theoretical Computer Science.

Is there any proof software that deals with Primitive Recursive Arithmetic... or equivalent systems?

Answer (score 1):

The [ACL2](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/v7-1/acl2-doc.html) theorem prover seems quite close to what you want, though it is hard to know exactly what the strength of the system is.

From the logical description [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/publications/km97a.pdf) it looks like the base is a quantifier-free equational logic with induction principles, which include principles allowing the definition of PR functions.

This gives exactly PRA, but in addition, the standard library defines induction up to $\varepsilon_0$, which brings the strength up to full Peano Arithmetic.

You might therefore want to work in ACL2 with a restricted version of the standard induction principle (I don't know how hard that is).